# Use Vim with virtualenv

Tags: external-command

I do a lot of Python and I use almost all the time a [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/) along with [virtualenvwrapper](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to keep my modules organised.

But when I want to use those plugin from inside vim, through an external command, it seems that the shell is not aware of that config.

I need to have access to the `virtualenv` because

e.g.

```
(venv) $ python
>> import simple_history
>> # OK here

(venv) $ vim
:!python 
>> import simple_history
ImportError: No module named simple_history
```

My shell is `shell=/bin/zsh`, I guess I need to use this setting to access my `virtualenv`, but I can't figure out how...

Comment: can use this too. https://github.com/jmcantrell/vim-virtualenv

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I actually fixed this myself a long time ago.  The problem is that when you run `!python` you're starting up a new shell with your existing environment.  But, this means `workon xxxx` wasn't called to actually activate the virtualenv.  This lead to a lot of confusion for me since `$VIRTUAL_ENV` was set.

I got around it by adding the following to my `~/.zshenv` script:

```
if [[ -n $VIRTUAL_ENV && -e "${VIRTUAL_ENV}/bin/activate" ]]; then
  source "${VIRTUAL_ENV}/bin/activate"
fi
```

Since `~/.zshenv` is sourced within the current session, it's a pretty safe assumption that the `$VIRTUAL_ENV` wasn't activated.  Now when you run `!python` in Vim, it should use the virtualenv interpreter.  You can confirm this by running `:echo system('which python')`.

Comment: Oh this is nice, maybe it's not the place to ask the question, but why should your snippet be in `.zshenv` instead of `.zshrc`?

Comment: @Nobe4 Because `.zshrc` is [not always sourced](https://rvm.io/integration/vim), while `.zshenv` is guaranteed to be sourced.

Comment: Here is further information about the load order of zsh scripts: http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Intro/intro_3.html

Comment: I updated the answer because `$ZSHENV_PATH_SET` is irrelevant to solving the OP's problem.  Adding the check for `$VIRTUAL_ENV` in that block was the result of late night troubleshooting.

Comment: to use with fish, i created ~/.config/fish/auto_source_venv.fish
`
if test -e $VIRTUAL_ENV
 source $VIRTUAL_ENV/bin/activate.fish
end
`
and added `. ~/.config/fish/auto_source_venv.fish` to `~/.config/fish/config.fish`

Answer (score 4):

For **neovim** and **pyenv** (also works for other python version managers that uses `$VIRTUAL_ENV` such as **virtualenvwrapper**) users with the same problem on nvim (venv not working properly, causing errors on `:checkhealth` and `!python`, etc), I know this is a little late, but since neovim `checkhealth` redirects to this question, I'm putting this answer here hoping it will help someone.

I created a function to autosource `$VIRTUAL_ENV` before calling `nvim`. This is a little different from Tommy A answer because venv is activated on the entire nvim env, fixing `!python` but also letting nvim to successfully detect the pyenv venv (see `:checkhealth`).

*For `pyright` problems, check PPS note at the bottom of this answer.*

Here is how I did with **fish**:

Create file `~/.config/fish/functions/nvimvenv.fish` and save the content below in it:

```
# Autosource virtualenv; Workaround for nvim
function nvimvenv
  if test -e "$VIRTUAL_ENV"; and test -f "$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin/activate.fish"
    source "$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin/activate.fish"
    command nvim $argv # Run nvim program, ignore functions, builtins and aliases
    deactivate # Must deactivate on exit, otherwise venv will still be sourced which may cause undesirable effects on your terminal.
  else
    command nvim $argv # Run nvim program, ignore functions, builtins and aliases
  end
end;
```

There is no need to source it.

To use this function just open a new terminal and run `nvimvenv`, or you can set an alias to nvim by running `alias nvim=nvimvenv` on terminal and call it with `nvim`. If you want to make it permanent run with `-s` option like `alias -s nvim=nvimvenv`.

**Important:** If after setting the script neovim venv still not working, check if you don't have `omf pyenv` installed. I found that when you have `omf pyenv` istalled neovim can't detect pyenv virtualenv. To uninstall just run `omf remove pyenv`, you don't need it to use pyenv in fish, just follow the pyenv fish installation guide and your are good.

Here is the same function for **bash** and **zsh** (you will need to put/source this on your `.bashrc` or `.zshrc`):

```
function nvimvenv {
  if [[ -e "$VIRTUAL_ENV" && -f "$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin/activate" ]]; then
    source "$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin/activate"
    command nvim "$@"
    deactivate
  else
    command nvim "$@"
  fi
}

alias nvim=nvimvenv
```

**PS:** Also works for **vim**, just replace nvim for vim in the script, but if your concern is only running the right `!python` Tommy answer will be enough.

**PPS - Regarding `pyright`:** Initially I erroneously mentioned that this workaround would fix `pyright` problems, but I found it was not true, it only fix `!python` and pyenv virtualenvs detection on nvim (`:checkhealth`). If you are facing problems with `pyright` you will probably have to setup a `pyrightconfig.json` with your venv. I created this plugin [pyenv-pyright](https://github.com/alefpereira/pyenv-pyright) to easily setup the `pyrightconfig.json` with pyenv virtualenvs.

Comment: You can use `command nvim` in bash/zsh to force the shell to not use aliases/functions in that position. That avoids hard-coding `/usr/bin/nvim`, which may not be correct for everyone.

Comment: Didn't know about `command`, thank you Ben, this also works on fish. Edited.

Comment: Still doesn't work for me with nvim and pyenv. `CheckHealth` gives `But $PATH yields this python3-config executable: Usage: /home/USERNAME/.pyenv/versions/3.12.1/envs/VENVNAME/bin/python3-config --prefix|--exec-prefix|--includes|--libs|--cflags|--ldflags|--extension-suffix|--help|--abiflags|--configdir|--embed`

Comment: Despite the previous warnings  in `:CheckHealth`, it works correctly with `pyright` **without the additional plugin advertised in PPS**. `pyright` is not signaling missing packages that are installed in the correct virtual environment. Instead, it does not work with `python-lsp-server`.